# Twilio Chat User (Node.js) friendlyName is not registered during access token creation

Tags: firebase, jwt, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I am trying to integrate **Twilio Programmable Chat SDK** with my Firebase Function, which is written in Typescript.

I am wondering if the **friendlyName and attributes** values could be set during the creation of the access token?

I have tried the following approaches, but still to no avail.

```
        const chatGrant = new ChatGrant({
            serviceSid: serviceSid,
            friendlyName : displayName,
            attributes : {
                profilePic : profilePic,
            }
        });
```

```
        const chatGrant = new ChatGrant({
            serviceSid: serviceSid,
        }, {
            friendlyName : displayName,
            attributes : {
                profilePic : profilePic,
            }
        });
```

```
        const chatGrant = new ChatGrant({
            serviceSid: serviceSid,
        });

        const token = new AccessToken(twilioAccountSid, twilioApiKey, twilioApiSecret);
        token.addGrant(chatGrant);
        token.identity = context.auth.uid;
        token.friendlyName : displayName,
        token.attributes : {
             profilePic : profilePic,
        }
```

Here is the entire code:

```
        // displayName and profilePic initialization ...

        const AccessToken = require('twilio').jwt.AccessToken;
        const ChatGrant = AccessToken.ChatGrant;

        // Used when generating any kind of tokens
        const twilioAccountSid = functions.config().twilio.account_sid;
        const twilioApiKey = functions.config().twilio.api_key;
        const twilioApiSecret = functions.config().twilio.api_secret;

        // Used specifically for creating Chat tokens
        const serviceSid = functions.config().twilio.chat_service_sid;

        // Create a "grant" which enables a client to use Chat as a given user,
        // on a given device
        const chatGrant = new ChatGrant({
            serviceSid: serviceSid,
            friendlyName : displayName,
            attributes : {
                profilePic : profilePic,
            }
        });

        // Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client,
        // containing the grant we just created
        const token = new AccessToken(twilioAccountSid, twilioApiKey, twilioApiSecret);
        token.addGrant(chatGrant);
        token.identity = context.auth.uid;

        // Serialize the token to a JWT string
        return {identity: token.identity, token: token.toJwt()};
```

I couldn't find anything related to this in the documentation. It would be great if the documentation could be made [clearer](https://guides.lib.berkeley.edu/how-to-write-good-documentation). Especially, for the Programmable Chat SDK part.

For instance, it would really helpful for us, developers, if we know the constructor's arguments (e.g. what are the arguments of the ChatGrant constructor?).

Thanks a heap!

Answer (score 0):

In my view, for program chat, access token is only used to get access to chat service so there is not friendly name relates to it. After you successfully entered the chat service, you need a "service role" to actually perform operations. At this stage, you started to use "friendly name"